# Retornar 2 consultas PDO em JSON

Tags: json, array, pdo

Preciso retornar duas consultas.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = end(explode('editarnovoservico', $id));

$searchid = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM cad_servicos WHERE id = '.$id);
$searchid = $searchid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$searchtiposervico = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM tipo_servicos');
$searchtiposervico = $searchtiposervico->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$array['searchid'] = $searchid;
$array['searchtiposervico'] = $searchtiposervico;

foreach ($array['searchtiposervico'] as $key => $value) {
    $array['searchtiposervico'][$key]['id'] = $value['id'];
    $array['searchtiposervico'][$key]['tipo_servico'] = utf8_encode($value['tipo_servico']);
}

$array['searchid'] = $searchid;
var_dump($array);
$array2['searchtiposervico'] = $searchtiposervico;
var_dump($array2);
```

O primeiro retorna:

```
array(1) {
  ["searchid"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "402"
      ["nome"]=>
      string(7) "bla bla"
      ["cobrado"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["id_tipo_servico"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["novo"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

E o segundo:

```
array(2) {
  ["searchtiposervico"]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(12) "Desconhecido"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(8) "Liga��es"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(3) "Sms"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(9) "Descontos"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(6) "Multas"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(8) "Parcelas"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(8) "Internet"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "8"
      ["tipo_servico"]=>
      string(11) "Assinaturas"
    }
  }
}
```

Como eu retornaria os dois em um `JSON`? tentei juntar os dois `array` e depois dá um `json_encode()`, mas não deu certo.

**~edit**: Após fazer um `foreach` percorrendo os dados com `utf8_encode()`, cosegui... mas fica gabiarra. hhaha =)

```
$array['searchid'] = $searchid;
$array['searchtiposervico'] = $searchtiposervico;   
foreach ($array['searchtiposervico'] as $key => $value) {
    $array['searchtiposervico'][$key]['id'] = $value['id'];
    $array['searchtiposervico'][$key]['tipo_servico'] =  utf8_encode($value['tipo_servico']);
}
echo json_encode($array, true);
```

Comment: Você pode mesclar os `arrays` com a função [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php) e depois usar o `json_encode`.

Comment: Tentei isso também, não deu certo, acabei de entender que tem algo haver com o UTF8. fiz um foreach percorrendo os dados e colocando utf8_encode(), deu certo... mas fica mais gambiarra aindo no meu código =)

Comment: Da forma que mostrei também funcionou ai?

Comment: Funcionou sim @zekk Agradeço muito ! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mesclar os `arrays` você pode usar a [função `array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php).

Sobre o erro ao usar a  função `json_encode()` é devido ao `array` não estar codificado adequadamente, ou seja, `UTF-8`.

Para resolver isto você pode fazer:

1. Usar a função `utf8_encode()` em cada item do `array`.
2. Passar como parâmetro a constante `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` na  função`json_encode`.

Exemplo:

```
$arraySearchId = array('searchid' => array(
                '0' => array(
                'id' => '1', 
                'nome' => 'bla',
                'cobrado' => '1',
                ),
));

$arraySearchServico = array('searchtiposervico' => array(
                '0' => array(
                'id' => '1', 
                'tipo_servico' => "Ligacões",
                ),

                '1' => array(
                'id' => '2', 
                'tipo_servico' => 'SMS',
                ),              
));

$arrayResultado = array_merge($arraySearchId, $arraySearchServico);

$json = json_encode($arrayResultado, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
print_r($json);
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/jH3mPa)